# Unit testing trait with object

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.0

I have the following construct, where I have a

```
trait DataServiceLocalImpl extends DataService {
  override lazy val dataService = DataComponentLocalImpl
}

object DataComponentLocalImpl extends DataComponent {
  def getData(element:String):String = GetStuffFromFile(element)
}

trait DataService {
  val dataService: DataComponent
}

trait DataComponent {
  def getData(element:String):String
}
```

The GetStuffFromFile reads a file from disk once (I only want this once, hence the object), creates a map and then returns the value for element.

This is all done in an Play Framework 2.3 surrounding and the app works as well, but when I use it in a test as an implicit I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class DataComponentLocalImpl`

Test suite:

```
class AutoCompleteSpec extends PlaySpec with Mockito with OneAppPerSuite {
  val resource = new DataServiceLocalImpl {}
  implicit val dataService = resource.dataService
}
```

If I remove the implicit it works...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should create an object with the service overriden.

```
  object FakeImpl extends DataServiceLocalImpl {
    override dataService = //Fake or test data service here
  }
```

You then create an anonymous class definition that allows you to test the trait.

Comment: You can extend an object in scala?